# Ada - strange error - consistent version of gcc/gnatbind

Tags: gcc, ada, gnat

i'm trying to compile an Ada project.

I installed the current 2011 GNAT GPL package from Libre AdaCore, it contains the gcc compiler too.

The strange error is the following

```
fatal error: file dom.ali is incorrectly formatted
make sure you are using consistent versions of gcc/gnatbind
```

if i type which gcc it gives me /usr/gnat/bin/gcc 
if i type which gnatbind it gives me /usr/gnat/bin/gnatbind

The content of "the incorrectly formatted" file is the following

```
V "GNAT Lib v2011"
A -gnat05
A -gnatA
P ZX
R nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnvnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn

U dom%s         dom.ads         2bd88f63 NE OO PK IU
D dom.ads       20090519080656 2bd88f63
D system.ads        20110419093140 2d1a1afa
X 1 dom.ads
44K9*DOM 46l5 46e8
```

Any clue?

Thank you in advance

Edit: `gnatls -v` shows the following (formatted for readability),

```
GNATLS GPL 2011 (20110419)
 Copyright (C) 1997-2011, Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Source Search Path: <Current_Directory>
    /usr/gnat/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/adainclude/
Object Search Path: <Current_Directory>
    /usr/gnat/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/adalib/
Project Search Path: <Current_Directory> 
    /usr/gnat/i686-pc-linux-gnu/lib/gnat
    /usr/gnat/share/gpr /usr/gnat/lib/gnat
```

Comment: What does `gnatls -v` say? (should begin GNATLS GPL 2011...) And what OS are you using?

Comment: BTW: The language is called "Ada", not "ADA". It is a name, not an abbreviation.

Comment: GNATLS GPL 2011 (20110419)<br>
Copyright (C) 1997-2011, Free Software Foundation, Inc.

    
Source Search Path:
       <Current_Directory>
       /usr/gnat/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/adainclude/



Object Search Path:
   <Current_Directory>
   /usr/gnat/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/adalib/



Project Search Path:
   <Current_Directory>
   /usr/gnat/i686-pc-linux-gnu/lib/gnat
   /usr/gnat/share/gpr
   /usr/gnat/lib/gnat

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad identation, OS is ubuntu 11.04. About Ada, you're right.

Comment: Since it's complaining about dom.ali, I take it you're using XMLAda. Did you download and install that as per its directions when you retrieved and installed GNAT GPL 2011? If you're using a gpr configuration file, are you 'withing' the right XMLAda gpr file? If you're using GPS project management, is your project dependency on the right XMLAda gpr file? If you're using gnatmake on the command line, are you including the right XMLAda directories?

Comment: You are right, i had to recompile xmlada with the recent Gnat compiler, now it works, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All compilation units have to be compiled with exactly the same GNAT version and used library versions. If you use precompiled libraries, you might have to recompile them.

See the [Debian Ada Policy](http://people.debian.org/~lbrenta/debian-ada-policy.html#Ada-Library-Information-files) part about ali files.

Comment: Finally that was the case, i was using an old XMLAda compiled with an old GNAT, recompiling it with latest one everything worked perfectly.